# JavaScript template for a HAML based view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have a Ruby on Rails application that is using HAML based template views. I need to drop a simple:

`alert('Hello World');` JavaScript excerpt template that I can build off that loads for the page.

If my controller's name is `Foo` and my actions name is `bar`, I put a `bar.js.haml` into `app/views/foo/` and it doesn't seem to load any of that JS when I load the page up.

What can I do to debug this and get JavaScript embedded into my haml views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, it's not going to auto include or auto reference another script for you. If you want to add javascript to the page using HAML:

```
:javascript
  alert('Hellooooooooooo');
```

Update with way to link to javascript file named "bar.js" in app/assets/javascripts

```
= javascript_include_tag "bar"
```

Comment: So as soon as you go HAML, you cannot include js the `traditional` Rails way? It has to be embedded directly into the HAML template itself?

Comment: No... if you are simply trying to link to a javascript file using a script tag, I'll update the answer.